# Understanding MDN Documentation of ShiftKey Event Property

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, keyboard-events

When looking up the ShiftKey Event property of the MouseEvent or the KeyboardEvent I noticed that under the **Specification** header the status is set to **Obsolete**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey#specifications

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey#specifications

Now I'm left wondering what this means, am I to take that the ShiftKey property is flagged as Obsolete and therefor can't be trusted to always work in browsers? If so, any clue on why this was abandoned?

Keeping track of whether the shift key is pressed through keydown and keyup events isn't that hard, but it's really an extra step I wouldn't want to have to take if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit confusing. :-) `shiftKey` isn't obsolete. What the Specifications table was telling you was that the specification it was linking to on that row is obsolete. Both of the specs listed have been superceded by the [UI Events specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/); `shiftKey` is defined in that spec [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#idl-mouseevent). (If you followed the link to the DOM3 spec, it would have given you a link to the UI Events spec.)

MDN's specifications stuff is data-driven. It looks like the entries for the two links specs have been marked obsolete, but the page for `shiftKey` hasn't been updated to link to the current spec it's defined in.